# Unknown XSLT parse error

Tags: xml, node.js, xslt, openxml

I created an XSL transform that to transform MS Word documents (OpenXML) into HTML.

The transform works fine if I link it to the XML file with:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="word-transform.xsl"?>
```

And then open the XML file in a browser—like FireFox.

But if I try to parse the transform with something like [node_xslt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_xslt) or an [online transformer](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html), I get an "unable to parse" error.

My question is basically what would cause a parse error in one situation but not in the other?

I've included the XSLT and the main XML file below (a Word doc is actually several XML files), including the HTML that that is generated (when I use FireFox).

**Note**   These files are huge! So I'm also interested in guesses or suggestions for how to find the error myself.

Thanks!

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
  xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
  xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
  xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
  xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
  xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
  xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
  xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
  xmlns:rel="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
  mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Other files -->
  <xsl:variable name="wordDoc">document</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="relFilename" select="'document.xml.rels'" />

  <xsl:variable name="relLoc">
    <xsl:value-of select="$wordDoc" />
    <xsl:text>/word/_rels/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$relFilename" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="rels" select="document($relLoc)/rel:Relationships" />

  <!-- Paragraph level styles -->
  <xsl:variable name="title">Title</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="h1">Heading1</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="h2">Heading2</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="h3">Heading3</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="h4">Heading4</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="h5">Heading5</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="codePara">Codeparagraph</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="list">ListParagraph</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="noSpaceList">No-spacelist</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="captionStyle">Caption</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="noteStyle">Note</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="quotePara">Quote</xsl:variable>

  <!-- Class names -->
  <xsl:variable name="captionClass">caption</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="noteClass">well</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="highlightClass">highlight</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="noSpaceClass">no-space</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="imageClasses">image figure img-polaroid</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="prettyPrint">prettyprint</xsl:variable>

  <!-- Character level styles -->
  <xsl:variable name="link">Hyperlink</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="codeChar">Codecharacter</xsl:variable>

  <!-- ol and ul designations used by Word -->
  <xsl:variable name="ul">0</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="ol">1</xsl:variable>

  <!-- Image styles -->
  <xsl:variable name="figure">figure</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="window">window</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="image">image</xsl:variable>

  <!-- Used for creating human-readable formatting -->
  <xsl:variable name="br"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="tab"><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

  <!-- Each block (paragraph, heading, etc.) is wrapped in w:p -->
  <xsl:template match="w:p">
    <!-- Determine the paragraph style -->
    <xsl:variable name="pStyle">
      <xsl:value-of select="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Apply appropriate heading styles -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $title">
        <h1>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $h1">
        <h1>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $h2">
        <h2>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $h3">
        <h3>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $h4">
        <h4>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h4>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $h5">
        <h5>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </h5>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- Apply custom paragraph styles -->
      <!-- Code sample paragraph -->
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $codePara">
        <pre>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="$prettyPrint" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates /></pre>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $quotePara">
        <blockquote><xsl:apply-templates /></blockquote>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- check if it's a list paragraph-->
      <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $list or $pStyle = $noSpaceList">
        <xsl:variable name="prevStyle">
          <xsl:for-each select="preceding::w:p">
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
              <xsl:value-of select="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val" />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- if it's the first list paragraph -->
        <xsl:if test="$prevStyle != $list and $prevStyle != $noSpaceList">
          <ul>
            <!-- add $noSpaceList class if applicable -->
            <xsl:if test="$pStyle = $noSpaceList">
              <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="$noSpaceClass" />
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
            <xsl:call-template name="add-list-element" />
          </ul>
          <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- Apply paragraph formatting to the plain old paragraphs -->
      <xsl:otherwise >
        <p>
          <!-- Add paragraph level classes -->
          <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Add $captionClass if it's a caption -->
            <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $captionStyle">
              <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="$captionClass" />
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$pStyle = $noteStyle">
              <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="$noteClass" />
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
          <!-- Apply the applicable templates -->
          <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
          <xsl:apply-templates />
          <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
        </p>
        <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- add li elements if the paragraph is a list -->
  <xsl:template name="add-list-element">
    <!-- store the paragraph's style -->
    <xsl:variable name="pStyle">
        <xsl:value-of select="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- If it's a list... -->
    <xsl:if test="$pStyle = $list or $pStyle = $noSpaceList">
      <xsl:value-of select="$tab" />
      <li><xsl:apply-templates /></li>
      <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
      <!-- recursively add li elements to the following list paragraphs -->
      <xsl:for-each select="following::w:p">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:call-template name="add-list-element" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add image -->
  <xsl:template match="a:blip">
    <!-- get the ID value -->
    <xsl:variable name="imageId">
      <xsl:value-of select="@r:embed" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Return the image with that ID -->
    <xsl:variable name="imageSRC">
      <xsl:value-of select="$rels/rel:Relationship[@Id=$imageId]/@Target" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Create the image tag -->
    <img>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="$wordDoc"/>
        <xsl:text>/word/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$imageSRC" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="$imageClasses" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="alt">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add hyperlinks -->
  <xsl:template match="w:hyperlink">
    <!-- For the actual href, look in document.xml.rels -->
    <xsl:variable name="linkId">
      <xsl:value-of select="@r:id" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="anchor">
      <xsl:if test="@w:anchor">
        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@w:anchor" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="$rels/rel:Relationship[@Id=$linkId]/@Target" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$anchor" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$href" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <!-- add 'type="anchor"' to anchors—used for smooth scrolling -->
      <xsl:if test="substring($href,1,1) = '#'">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
          <xsl:text>anchor</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r" />
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:br">
    <br />
    <xsl:value-of select="$br" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$tab" />
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- output paragraph text; one paragraph (w:p) might contain multiple w:r tags -->
  <xsl:template match="w:r">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:br" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- Styles (e.g., strong and em) are in w:rPr -->
      <xsl:when test="w:rPr">
        <!-- w:rPr contains multiple styles, and each style handles applying templates to the next one, so we here we apply templates only to the first style -->
        <xsl:for-each select="child::w:rPr/*">
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- text that isn't styled doesn't have a w:rPr-->
      <xsl:when test="not(w:rPr)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="w:t" />
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

    <!-- images -->
    <xsl:if test="w:drawing">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:drawing" />
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- inline styles (w:rPr) start -->
  <!-- style template: strong -->
  <xsl:template match="w:b">
    <strong>
      <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
    </strong>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- style template: Bold wtf -->
  <xsl:template match="w:bCs">
      <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- style template: emphasis -->
  <xsl:template match="w:i">
    <em>
      <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
    </em>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- style template: emphasis wtf -->
  <xsl:template match="w:iCs">
    <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- style template: highlight -->
  <xsl:template match="w:highlight">
    <span>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="$highlightClass" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- inline code -->
  <xsl:template match="w:rStyle[@w:val=$codeChar]">
    <code>
      <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
    </code>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- link -->
  <xsl:template match="w:rStyle[@w:val=$link]">
    <xsl:call-template name="print-text" />
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- inline styles end -->
  <xsl:template name="print-text">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="following-sibling::w:*">
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::w:*">
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="following::w:t">
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- All text is wrapped in w:t, so this actually prints the text -->
  <xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="self::*" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="word-transform2.xsl"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Here’s a sample doc!</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Founded in 1901 by Caleb </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Deffell</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">, </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="00831343">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:i />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Deffell's Pants</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> has been the industry innovator in leg coverings for over 100 years. When your great-grandmother first dared to put on a pair of trousers, she turned to </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Deffells</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>. That sentiment is still a big pa</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>rt of our design process today.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Quote" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">"Everyone wears pants. </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Except those who don't.</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> That's why we make </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>jorts</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">." —Caleb </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Deffell</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>With that sentiment in mind, I'm happy to announce the latest in</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>novation in the Deffell's line:</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Design your own jeans</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Send us your measurements and pick the</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>:</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Fabric</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Stitching</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Leather patch</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Buttons</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Rivets</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Zippers</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="No-spacelist" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>And every aspect</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">And we'll build a pair of </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>jeans just the way you want it.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Hire a designer</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Or if you're not sure about all those options, tell us what you do in your jeans. Send us pictures of yourself skateboarding, running, breakdancing, </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>parkour-ing</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>, walking your cat, o</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>r whatever else you like to do.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00831343" w:rsidRDefault="00831343" w:rsidP="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Our top designers will analyze your life and build the jeans tha</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>t will work just right for you.</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="003D4B67" w:rsidRDefault="00831343">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">So go on, </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">order your custom jeans to </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="00831343">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>now</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>!</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="003D4B67" w:rsidSect="00345542">
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1800" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1800" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="720" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Here’s a sample doc!</h1>
<p>
Founded in 1901 by Caleb Deffell, <em>Deffell's Pants</em> has been the industry innovator in leg coverings for over 100 years. When your great-grandmother first dared to put on a pair of trousers, she turned to Deffells. That sentiment is still a big part of our design process today.
</p>
<blockquote>"Everyone wears pants. Except those who don't. That's why we make jorts." —Caleb Deffell</blockquote>
<p>
With that sentiment in mind, I'm happy to announce the latest innovation in the Deffell's line:
</p>
<h2>Design your own jeans</h2>
<p>
Send us your measurements and pick the: 
</p>
<ul class="no-space">
  <li>Fabric</li>
  <li>Stitching</li>
  <li>Leather patch</li>
  <li>Buttons</li>
  <li>Rivets</li>
  <li>Zippers</li>
  <li>And every aspect</li>
</ul>
<p>
And we'll build a pair of jeans just the way you want it.
</p>
<h2>Hire a designer</h2>
<p>
Or if you're not sure about all those options, tell us what you do in your jeans. Send us pictures of yourself skateboarding, running, breakdancing, parkour-ing, walking your cat, or whatever else you like to do.
</p>
<p>
Our top designers will analyze your life and build the jeans that will work just right for you.
</p>
<p>
So go on, order your custom jeans to <strong>now</strong>!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is basically what would cause a parse error in one
>   situation but not in the other?

IMHO, the availability of the external document which your XSLT requires on line #37:

```
<xsl:variable name="rels" select="document($relLoc)/rel:Relationships" />
```

Testing with Saxon points to more issues with your stylesheet, namely:

- *The match pattern in xsl:template may not contain references to variables*

I guess the other processors you tried were more tolerant in this aspect.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. I guess the solution is XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Either that or rewrite in proper XSLT 1.0 syntax.